# iPad: Launch MainWindow.xib's primary view without using InterfaceBuilder confi

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, interface-builder

I get really confused using InterfaceBuilder to setup the main window xib file's primary controller view.  Is there a good example or simple way to launch the ViewController I want to show by default in the Application Delegate instead of setting it up in InterfaceBuilder's MainWindow.xib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show your view by code as

FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

[window addSubView:fvc];

Comment: What's the purpose of setting in up in UIBuilder?  What defined the "primary" view?  Is it just the first one you addSubView on the window with?

Comment: What about the view in the MainWindow.xib file that just kind of hangs out there?  I am using an open source splitview controller and it is hard to setup in UIBuilder.  Do I just put a place holder view in MainWindow.xib?